# Recording Google Earth Tour, elements switched on timing wrong

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am trying to record a Google Earth tour with audio using Google Earth client.  I press record and turn layers on and off but the layers timing is off, commonly the error produces:

element 1:  on at start
element 2: turns on when element 1 should have turned on
element 3: turns on when element 2 should have
etc.

sometimes the wrong element turns on at the wrong time in a different way.

I could hand edit the KML but that would take forever with the tours I want to produce and it would be difficult (and complex) to add audio in via KML.  I know about GE Studio, I haven't had a lot of joy with it for creating tours so am interested in other options.

I've tried this on v6.1 on XP and OSX 10.7 - same issue.

Any solutions to this?  is it a known issue?  I can't find reference to it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on GE v5.1 the issue doesn't arise so its been introduced by v6